# Ruby on Rails 4 Heroku App Crash while uploading large size video

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, paperclip

large video file isn't uploading on heroku and throwing Application Crash error
Here is my Model Code:

```
has_attached_file :video, :styles => {
  :medium => {
    :geometry => "640x480",
    :format => 'mp4',
    :convert_options => {
    :output => {
      :vcodec => 'libx264',
      :acodec => 'copy'
    }
  }
  },
  :thumb => {
    :geometry => "300x300#",
    :format => 'jpg',
    :time => 2,
    :auto_rotate => true
  }
}, :processors => [:transcoder]

validates_attachment_content_type :video, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
```

Here is my log from heroku

```
2016-07-22T13:15:13.616340+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/33028ec79c8028f75908c90d9f018aeb20160722-3-1e90wvf.mp4'
2016-07-22T13:15:13.771935+00:00 app[web.1]: [AV] Running command: if command -v avprobe 2>/dev/null; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
2016-07-22T13:15:13.773078+00:00 app[web.1]: [AV] Running command: if command -v ffmpeg 2>/dev/null; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
2016-07-22T13:15:13.774121+00:00 app[web.1]: [AV] Found ["ffmpeg"], using: Ffmpeg
2016-07-22T13:15:13.774159+00:00 app[web.1]: [AV] Running command: if command -v avprobe 2>/dev/null; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
2016-07-22T13:15:13.775225+00:00 app[web.1]: [AV] Running command: if command -v ffmpeg 2>/dev/null; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
2016-07-22T13:15:13.776771+00:00 app[web.1]: [AV] Found ["ffmpeg"], using: Ffmpeg
2016-07-22T13:15:13.776807+00:00 app[web.1]: [AV] Running command: ffmpeg -i "/tmp/33028ec79c8028f75908c90d9f018aeb20160722-3-xbemwt.mp4" 2>&1
2016-07-22T13:15:13.814982+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] [transcoder] Transocding supported file /tmp/33028ec79c8028f75908c90d9f018aeb20160722-3-xbemwt.mp4
2016-07-22T13:15:13.815056+00:00 app[web.1]: [AV] Adding output parameter ["acodec", "aac"]
2016-07-22T13:15:13.815103+00:00 app[web.1]: [AV] Adding output parameter ["strict", "experimental"]
2016-07-22T13:15:13.815289+00:00 app[web.1]: [AV] Adding output parameter [:s, "640x480"]
2016-07-22T13:15:13.815379+00:00 app[web.1]: [AV] Running command: ffmpeg -i "/tmp/33028ec79c8028f75908c90d9f018aeb20160722-3-xbemwt.mp4" -acodec aac -strict experimental -s 640x480 -y "/tmp/33028ec79c8028f75908c90d9f018aeb20160722-3-xbemwt20160722-3-1pwdg2k.mp4"
2016-07-22T13:15:43.237749+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/courses/5/sections/7/lessons/11" host=xxxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=a1408ac7-c7c3-40f4-8365-86156d2d2314 fwd="43.255.56.1" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=188655ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Comment: Would be very helpful if you have Stacktrace and the exception message from the heroku logs.

Comment: @SriVishnuTotakura I have pasted my log info in the question description

Answer (score 1):

Its clearly a `Request Timeout`. Check [heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout) on how they suggest the request timeouts to be handled.

Request timeout happen when a HTTP request takes too long to respond back to the user. The servers or in this case, heorku's router which handles the requests will kill a request if it doesn't respond within a set timeout.

This could have been happening because the file size is large and it takes more time to either upload or process it. I would suggest you do perform such uploads directly from Javascript to S3 or use background workers to perform the job. This means, you need to re-address how your upload feature is provided to your users.

Check [Heroku's post](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#direct-upload) on Direct uploads from user's browser to S3

Comment: You are saying to upload large files directly to S3. But I need to generate thumbnails using ffmpeg transcoder also. What about ffmpeg?

Comment: Then you will have to first upload to S3 directly from browser. Once saved to S3, then do the generation of thumbnails. If that takes quite some time, use some background workers to pick up those recently saved videos, process them in the background and use some callbacks to show status to the user.